# auto save/submit form on page/browser close/exit

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form with a save button, but i want users to be able to come back to the form at anytime to finish filling it in. I would like to know if its possible to bypass the save button, so the user fills part of the form in, as soon as they navigate away from the page or close their browser it will save the form automatically to resume next time.

What would be the best way to implement this? Thanks in advance for any help, its much appreciated.

I have seen some javascript examples but have seen issues with cross browser support.

Comment: What does 'Save' do? Send it to a server or store it in cookies/localStorage?

Comment: the magic words are `onclose` and `ajax`

Comment: @pimvdb: Save button submits form to php, which saves to mysql db

Comment: @Matthew Brennand: Then I'm not aware of a solution. When the page is closed you cannot just fire another request and wait for the response. You might instead want to store it client-side (e.g. in cookies) and read from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery plugin, works a treat for autosave function.
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-autosave

More info here:
http://rikrikrik.com/jquery/autosave/#examples

include plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.autosave.js"></script>
    $('form.formnamehere').autosave({
      'interval': 20000
    });
```

Auto submits form without page refresh.

I have set my interval to one second (1000) so the form gets saved every second. Therefor if the user exits the form after editing then it has autosaved.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an AJAX Call on unload like this:

```
window.onunload = myfunc();

function myfunc() {
  alert("i am closing now");
  // Your AJAX Call that saves your data (e.g. all input fields)
}
```

Comment: thanks, i have just tried this but it seems to work on page load rather than when i navigate away from the page.

Comment: You are sure that you did not use window.onload instead? :)

Comment: i copied and pasted the code above, i have just used window.onunload=function() {
    document.checklist.submit();
    } and it seems to work great. Apart from when you navigate away it submits and save the form, but then returns you back to the page the form was on, even though you click on another link.