# Mail or submit filled form data on page close or page unload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, onunload

I want to submit or mail the fully filled or partially filled form data when the user closes the page or hit the back button of the browser. Is it possible to create such an environment using jQuery or JavaScript? I am not aware of onunload event or beforeunload events and I couldn't find any working examples.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929832/send-ajax-to-server-beforeunload

Comment: You could submit the partially completed page to the server, using AJAX, either for every keystroke.

Comment: Thanks @halfer Let me check that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [auto save/submit form on page/browser close/exit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981590/auto-save-submit-form-on-page-browser-close-exit)